# Remove draggable containment

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, containment

You can add containment dynamically like this:

```
$(this).draggable( "option", "containment", "parent" );
```

How do i remove the containment again?
Like:

```
$(this).draggable( "option", "containment", "none" );
```

except that doesn't work.. I could not find any methods for it in the API documentation

EDIT: I want to be able to drag the item but with no containment. I am using this with checkboxes:

```
        var denne = $(this);
        if ($('#containment').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).draggable( "option", "containment", "parent" );
        }
        $("#containment").each(function(){
            if ($(this).prop('checked')==false){ 
                denne.draggable( "option", "containment", false );
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you want specifically? Do you want to remove/disable the draggable or do you still want it draggable but not contained?  Or perhaps contained within different boundaries?

Comment: Passing "none" keeps the containment as parent?

Comment: Try $(this).draggable( "option", "containment", false );

Comment: Yes, "none" keeps it as "parent".
I want it to be draggable but not contained.
setting it to false didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do...

You could "disable" the element so that it is no longer draggable.

```
$(this).draggable( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Or you could change the containment boundaries so that the element can be draggable outside of the original constraints.

```
$(this).draggable( "option", "containment", "window" );
```

Or by specifying the exact boundaries.

```
$(this).draggable( "option", "containment", [x1, y1, x2, y2] );
```

Or as Menencia mentioned in the comments, you could try setting the containment to false

```
$(this).draggable( "option", "containment", false );
```

Comment: I must still be able to drag the item.. 
Setting the containment to "window" would not work for me.
Setting it to false like this didn't work at all.. :(

Comment: I believe false is working but not what you want.  What about setting to "document" instead of "window" or actually specifying the boundaries with `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`?

Comment: Great!  I will update my answer to include that option as well.